# PHP no me devuelve todos los resultados de una consulta a Oracle cuando hay muchos registros

Tags: php, base-de-datos, array, oracle

Estoy haciendo consultas desde PHP a una base de datos Oracle.

El problema es que cuando la base de datos tiene pocos registros (5 por ejemplo), cuando recorro la función *oci_fetch_array*, me los devuelve sin problema, pero cuando son 100 registros me devuelve **null**.

Est es el código:

```
$sql = oci_parse($this->db, "SELECT * FROM EMPRESAS ORDER BY ID DESC");
oci_execute($sql);

    $array = [];
    while ($row = oci_fetch_array($sql, OCI_ASSOC + OCI_RETURN_NULLS)) {
        array_push($array, $row);
    }

    return $array ? $array : null;
```

Me devuelve null porque el array está vacío.

¿Alguna idea de qué puede estar pasando?

He hecho debug y no entra al bucle. $row me devuelve false.

Estoy usando Oracle database 11g Express y PHP 5.6.

He probado también la función oci_error() y me devuelve false.

Hago el mismo select desde SQL Developer y me devuelve correctamente todas las filas.

Comment: Por favor muestra tu código de como lo estás haciendo para poder ayudarte.

Comment: He editado y añadido el código

Comment: Pero no has añadido lo mas importante, la quey.

Comment: La query no la he aladido porque es un simple select: SELECT * FROM EMPRESAS ORDER BY ID DESC

Comment: Que es un simple select unicamente lo sabes tu, los demas no sabemos que query es y por eso es importante ponerlo

Comment: Tienes razón. Añadido.

Comment: Se me hace rara la manera de crear un array con `$array = [];`. ¿Es correcta? Edito: ¡sí! Veo en php.net/array que vale a partir de PHP 5.4

Comment: ¿Has hecho debugging? Por ejemplo poniendo algún tipo de `print_r($row)` dentro del `while ()`.

Comment: Depende mucho este tipo de errores de la versión de PHP y de Oracle. Cuales son? http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/oow10/php_db/php_db.htm

Comment: Si, he hecho debug y no entra al bucle.$row = false. Estoy usando Oracle database 11g Express y PHP 5.6

Comment: He probado también la función oci_error() y me devuelve false...

Comment: Vale, he cambiado la publicación inicial.

Comment: No viene al caso, pero como curiosidad igual te vale:  `OCI_ASSOC + OCI_RETURN_NULLS` es lo mismo que `OCI_BOTH`, y es el modo por defecto, con lo cual, podrías omitirlo.

Comment: No tendras un limite de rows? A mi a veces me ha pasado, que al hacer la consulta limite la cantidad de lineas que te devuelve por si te aporte algo, saludos!

Comment: Estoy intentando reproducir tu problema con una tabla en la que tengo cerca de un millar de registros y no tengo ningún problema a la hora de obtenerlos todos. He probado con PHP 5.6 e instantclient 11.2 (x86_64) y OCI8 Version 2.0.6 en diferentes distribuciones donde hago uso de consultas a oracle: Debian 7 (apurando EOL), 8 y Ubuntu Server 16.04. ¿Podrías compartir información de versión de instantclient, sistema operativo y cómo has generado el módulo de oci8 y la versión que usas?

Comment: Es una pregunta de 2017. En su día resolví el problema pero no recuerdo la solución que le dí debido a que es un proyecto antiguo.

Comment: Cual es el valor del `$array` antes del return? Estoy casi seguro que es mejor en vez de usar array_push hacer simplemente $array[] = loquequieras y te lo va poniendo siempre en el ultimo puesto

Comment: Hola, amigo te recomiendo que pases por aquí: [tour] y que te leas estos artículos: [help/dont-ask], [help/on-topic], [help/behavior] y que arregles tu pregunta mirando este articulo: [mcve] tambien puedes pedir ayuda en: [chat]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prueba utilizar **oci_fetch_all**, ya que esto te almacena inmediatamente en un array.

```
$sql = oci_parse($this->db, "SELECT * FROM EMPRESAS ORDER BY ID DESC");
oci_execute($sql);

$nrows = oci_fetch_all($sql, $res, null, null, OCI_FETCHSTATEMENT_BY_ROW);

echo "$nrows filas obtenidas<br>\n";
var_dump($res); // la variable $res ya traeria un array con la información
```

Como nota personal te recomendaría también comenzar a revisar PDO.

Comment: Me devuelve 0 filas obtenidas y al imprimir el array se listan los nombres de las columnas de la bd sin resultados.

Comment: acabo de actualizar la respuesta, prueba con los atributos que agregue al oci_fetch_all

Comment: 0 filas obtenidas, y el array vacío (array (size=0))